# Ubuntu 22.04: docker: containers not accessible from outside

Tags: networking, 22.04, iptables, docker

having a fresh off the shelf Ubuntu 22.04 installation and installed docker according [the book](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

I also spinned up three containers using docker-compose and they show fine using `docker ps`.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                   PORTS                                                                                  NAMES
60cf25f59a92   jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest   "/init"                  48 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes             0.0.0.0:80-81->80-81/tcp, :::80-81->80-81/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   infra_nginx_proxy_1
f8081b137abf   graylog/graylog:4.2               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   55 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1514->1514/tcp, :::1514->1514/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp   infra_graylog_1
d3fef3332752   elasticsearch:7.9.3               "/tini -- /usr/local…"   55 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes             9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                                                     infra_elasticsearch_1
6b7920e89790   mongo:4.4.9                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   56 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes             27017/tcp                                                                              infra_mongo_db_1
```

Now, when trying to curl one of the locally, all fine

```
root$: curl http://localhost:81

<!doctype html><html lang="en" dir="ltr"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1">...
```

But the same curl (against the public IP of course) ends in timeout.

Doing tcpdump on the docker host reveals this, traffic is arriving

```
root$: tcpdump port 81
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
19:53:34.520888 IP 10.0.1.27.51942 > docker-infrastruktur.81: Flags [S], seq 1942358053, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1217328475 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:53:35.535503 IP 10.0.1.27.51942 > docker-infrastruktur.81: Flags [S], seq 1942358053, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1217329490 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:53:37.551436 IP 10.0.1.27.51942 > docker-infrastruktur.81: Flags [S], seq 1942358053, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1217331506 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:53:41.775510 IP 10.0.1.27.51942 > docker-infrastruktur.81: Flags [S], seq 1942358053, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1217335730 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

iptables - all docker generated - look like this

```
sudo iptables --list

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:81
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:1514

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

And even `nmap` shows that all doors are open

```
root$: sudo nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-08-12 19:56 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000013s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
81/tcp   open  hosts2-ns
443/tcp  open  https
9000/tcp open  cslistener
```

Interestingly, when spinning up a local webserver, e.g. with `python3 -m http.server 81` it spins up (after having shut down the containers) and it is reachable. So an issue with external firewall or even the host operating system I can quite of nail out...

Please help and advice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more analysing we found out a cause, or contributing factor: While installing the operating system it was chosen to also install docker.

Afterwards we did follow the installation guide (https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) and removed all "old" versions

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

Then we installed from the docker apt sources.

We did a fresh installation of the OS, this time not installing docker, et voilá: all fine after installing docker.

Comment: wow thats a rather... harsh solution but if that works, i'll do the same. I dont want to waste any more time with that.

Comment: Having ubuntu install docker as part of the OS install was the worst decision ever

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue (although my 22.04 was upgraded from 20.04). The symptoms were exactly the same so I share the solution here, maybe it helps someone. I tried reinstalling docker, as suggested here, but it didn't work. Reinstalling the server was not an option.

In the end, the issue was related to a bug with [iptables-nft and snap](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufw/+bug/1968608) (also reported to [docker-snap](https://github.com/docker-snap/docker-snap/issues/68)):

> Software that manipulates the firewall outside of the configured symlinks (or using iptables-legacy/iptables 1.6 while nftables is also in use) might introduce problems if they are not aware of the xtables/netfilter incompatibility. Eg, this might happen with snaps that ship their own iptables or nftables and unconditionally use it without considering existing rules on the system.
> [...]
> The 'docker' snap as of 20.10.12 in the stable channel is known to unconditionally use xtables. At the time of this filing, it did not have a way to adjust to using netfilter, so if using the docker snap, you might have to update your system to use iptables-legacy (on Debian/Ubuntu, see update-alternatives, above).

I found that `/etc/alternatives/iptables` was pointing to `/usr/sbin/iptables-nft`, but I also had `iptables-legacy` rules. See:

```
$ sudo iptables -S
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy to see them
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
...
$ sudo iptables-legacy -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
...
```

After discovering this, the solution was simply:

```
sudo iptables-legacy -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Comment: This worked.  I leveraged SNAP to install Docker on my 22.04 Ubuntu as a side note.  Due to this method of configuration I had to change the permissions of the docker socket along with leveraging the the sudo iptables-legacy -P FORWARD ACCEPT.

Comment: Ho thanks! It was exactly what I missed!

Answer (score 5):

No need to reinstall the whole system. Problem is the "snap" version of docker provided by the installer. If you install docker through apt afterwards, you'll end up having both binaries. Just remove the snap

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

And reinstall from official docker repository

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

check: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

This is what solved it for me. Note that I had installed docker through apt and was not using snap, but all the same, I came across the incompatibilit  between iptables-nft and iptables-legacy.

1. Using update-alternatives to switch to iptables-legacy

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
```

2. Restart docker

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

The exposed ports, that before were only available on localhost became available immediately.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: When installing Docker via SNAP, you will have several issues that will will make docker no longer run out of the box (as of 22.04). These include improper permissions to the raw sockets file, and inability to get access to exposed docker ports.

**Solution**:  The first command updates the firewall, the second command is used to increase the permissions on the socket descriptor.

```
sudo iptables-legacy -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Vote This Up If its useful.